# Increasing too small ImageView to 48dp touch target size?

Tags: android, material-design, accessibility

I have a `ImageView` with a 24x24 dp icon, so the complete `ImageView` and touch area is only 24x24dp, while the [recommended minimum touch target area](https://material.io/design/usability/accessibility.html#layout-and-typography) is 48x48dp.

What's the common way to increase the `ImageView` touch area size? I can add a padding of 12 dp on each side manually (24 + 12 + 12 = 48 dp), but is there any better way? Especially if the `ImageView` size changes I have to adjust padding manually, that's very error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the size of the `ImageView` to the size of the touchable area.

Then you set the scale type attribute of the `ImageView` to achieve the desired effect. In your case (icon is likely to be smaller than `48dp` x `48dp`) this could be `android:scaleType="center"` or `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:scaleType) for a description of all options

Comment: found that the most elegant solution for my case, thank you!

Comment: not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Using a `LinearLayout` and an `ImageView` together  may also be a solution.

Keep the imageView inside the LinearLayout and then set the size of linearLayout as `48dp` x `48dp` and keep the imageView size as `24dp` x `24dp and in case if you have any onclick event then you can just replace the ImageView's onclick event with the linearLayout.

Comment: thanks, that would be an option, but it can also be done alone with an ImageView (see answer of Bö)

Comment: In some case the answer of Bö may not worked if the size of the image is greater than the imageView's size. Then this could be helpful and I personally use this approach when my imageView size is smaller than the image size

Answer (score 0):

You can make the touch area bigger or smaller by changing the `layout-width` and `layout-height` properties.